# iOS AVfoundation overlay video with video

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation, gpuimage

I have main video and I want to overlay it with another animated video with alpha channel like "Action Movie FX" application. How can I do it with AVfoundation, or can you suggest third-party framework?

Thanks

Comment: you can set the frame of an avassetTrack within the player view using AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction

Answer (score 0):

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/) by Brad Larson is a great third-party framework for this kind of thing. It has many different blending algorithms you can choose from. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397259/adding-image-to-video-using-gpuimage) has code similar to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at my 3rd party framework to do this sort of task under iOS. You can find example Xcode projects named [AVRender](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVRender) and [Fireworks](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#Fireworks) that show the exact kind of composition you describe. The compositions could be done either offline or online and can be implemented fully lossless or with a lossy encoding to h.264 as the final output. That main thing is that you will want to use a technology with a full alpha channel as h.264 does not support an alpha channel by default.