# Video Overlapping in iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, avfoundation, gpuimage, avmutablecomposition

I'm working on an app where I have to overlap an alpha channel video over a video recorded from the device camera. Is it possible using GPUImage framework? 
If **YES** how can I implement it using GPUImage?
And if **NO** what alternative do I have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33860725/763355

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement it with GPUImage.
You need to use Blending filters of GPUImage.
Here you can find implementation. 
http://indieambitions.com/idevblogaday/mixing-videos-gpuimage/